# the distance traveled by a point rotating around a moving object?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a straightforward question. How to calculate the distance traveled by a point rotating a $\theta$ angle per second, with $r$ radius around an object which is moving in a straight line for a distance $d$ meter per second?

Comment: It depends on the speed of the movement.

Comment: I think you need to add something about how fast the object is moving in order to figure out this problem

Comment: yep, thanks I added a time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ and $R^\perp$ be two orthogonal vectors in the plane of rotation around the object and $V$ the direction of motion of the latter.

The trajectory is expressed by
$$P=R\cos\omega t+R^\perp\sin\omega t+Vt$$

and the instant speed is
$$\dot P=\omega(-R\sin\omega t+R^\perp\cos\omega t)+V.$$

Hence the squared modulus of the speed
$$\frac{ds^2}{dt^2}=R^2\omega^2+2(-RV\sin\omega t+R^\perp V\cos\omega t)\omega+V^2=\omega^2r^2+v^2+2\omega rv'\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$ where $v'$ is the projection of the speed on the normal to the plane.

In general, computing the distance takes an elliptic integral.

In the easy case that rotation is orthogonal to the displacement (helicoidal trajectory),

$$d=\sqrt{\omega^2r^2+v^2}t.$$

There is another tractable case when $$\omega^2r^2+v^2=2|\omega rv'|,$$ for example when rotation occurs in a plane parallel to the motion, with speeds such that the trajectory is a cycloid.

Comment: excuse me, it has been more than ten years since last time I read any note on Calculus, I'll accept the answer (seems right to me), but is there a special simplified case if the displacement of the object is in the same plane of the rotation, and on the X axis as well?
I am trying some coding for 2D physics and all the movements are on a 2D X-Y plane, both the rotation and the displacement.

Comment: @Physician: did you read the whole answer ?

Comment: yeah, before the edit you wrote in the last line if the plane was "orthogonal" to the motion as I remember.

Comment: Anyway, a cycloid requires "no slipping" in the motion. My case if generalizing to the cycloid with slipping added. Or in other words, the circular motion is in total asynch with the displacement.

Comment: @Physician: as written, computing the distance takes an elliptic integral.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of motion is of the form
$$
x(t)=\big(r\cos(\vartheta t),r\sin(\vartheta t)\big)+(dt,0)
$$
The distance travelled from time $0$ to time $T$ is given by
$$
D=\int_0^T |x'(t)|\,dt=\int_0^T
\big|\big(d-r\vartheta\sin(\vartheta t),r\vartheta\cos(\vartheta t)\big)\big|\,dt
=\cdots=\int_0^T\big(r^2\vartheta^2+d^2-2dr\vartheta\sin (\vartheta t)\big)^{1/2}dt.
$$
Unless $r^2\vartheta^2=d^2$, the above is an elliptic integral. No further simplification.

Comment: shouldn't that last term in the brackets be $-2dr\theta sin(\theta t)$

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks!